# Dropping rows in pandas based on a more complex condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
time        id  type
2012-12-19  1   abcF1
2013-11-02  1   xF1yz
2012-12-19  1   abcF1
2012-12-18  1   abcF1
2013-11-02  1   xF1yz
2006-07-07  5   F5spo
2006-07-06  5   F5spo
2005-07-07  5   F5abc
```

For a given id, I need to find the max date.

For that max date I need to check the type.

I have to drop every row for the given id if the type differs from the type of the max date.

Example for target data frame:

```
time        id  type
<deleted because for id 1 the date is not the max value and the type differs from the type of the max date for id 1>
2013-11-02  1   xF1yz
<deleted because for id 1 the date is not the max value and the type differs from the type of the max date for id 1>
<deleted because for id 1 the date is not the max value and the type differs from the type of the max date for id 1>
2013-11-02  1   xF1yz
2006-07-07  5   F5spo
2006-07-06  5   F5spo //kept because although the date is not max, it has the same type as the row with the max date for id 5
<deleted because for id 5 the date is not the max value and the type differs from the type of the max date for id 5>
```

How can I achieve this? 
I am new to pandas and trying to learn the proper way to use the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for get indices of max values, filter only columns `id` and `type` and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df.merge(df.loc[df.groupby('id')['time'].idxmax(), ['id','type']])
print (df)
        time  id   type
0 2013-11-02   1  xF1yz
1 2013-11-02   1  xF1yz
2 2006-07-07   5  F5spo
3 2006-07-06   5  F5spo
```

Or use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.merge(df.sort_values('time').drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')[["id", "type"]])
```

Comment: @DYZ - for second solution yes, for first not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the dataframe by time, then group by id and choose the last row in each group. That is the row with the largest date.

```
last_rows = df.sort_values('time').groupby('id').last()
```

Then merge the original dataframe with the new one:

```
result = df.merge(last_rows, on=["id", "type"])
#       time_x  id   type      time_y
#0  2013-11-02   1  xF1yz  2013-11-02
#1  2013-11-02   1  xF1yz  2013-11-02
#2  2006-07-07   5  F5spo  2006-07-07
#3  2006-07-06   5  F5spo  2006-07-07
```

If needed, drop the last duplicate column:

```
result.drop('time_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper `Series` using [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html). Then use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# If neccessary cast to datetime dtype
# df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

s = df.set_index('type').groupby('id')['time'].transform('idxmax')
df[df.type == s.values]
```

[out]

```
        time  id   type
1 2013-11-02   1  xF1yz
4 2013-11-02   1  xF1yz
5 2006-07-07   5  F5spo
6 2006-07-06   5  F5spo
```

Comment: @jezrael not sure i understand? How does this fail?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['2012-12-19', '2013-11-02', '2013-12-19', '2013-12-18', '2013-11-02', '2006-07-07', '2006-07-06', '2005-07-07'],
    'id': [1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5],
    'type': ['abcF1', 'xF1yz', 'abcF1', 'abcF1', 'xF1yz', 'F5spo', 'F5spo', 'F5abc']
})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
def remove_non_max_date_ids(df):
    max_type = df.loc[df['time'].idxmax()]['type']
    print(max_type)
    return df[
        df['type'] != max_type
    ]

df.groupby('id').apply(remove_non_max_date_ids)
```

Create a helper function that filters out the rows that do not have the same type as the max date, then apply it to each group df based on `id`

Answer (score 0):

The other way using [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# if needed
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# sort values of id and time ascendingly, and tagged the duplicates
df = df.sort_values(by=['id','time'], ascending=[True,True])
df['time_max'] = df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep='last')
# keep the max value only
df2 = df.loc[~df['time_max'],['id','type']].rename(columns={'type':'type_max'}).copy()

# merge with the original df
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['id'], how='left')
# get the result
df['for_drop'] = df['type']==df['type_max']
df = df.loc[df['for_drop'],:]
```

[out]:

```
df
    time        id  type    time_max    type_max    for_drop
3   2013-11-02  1   xF1yz   True          xF1yz       True
4   2013-11-02  1   xF1yz   False         xF1yz       True
6   2006-07-06  5   F5spo   True          F5spo       True
7   2006-07-07  5   F5spo   False         F5spo       True
```